# Fullcalendar JSON Feed Caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

How can I get [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) to cache events from a JSON feed?

I don't think [`lazyfetching`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/lazyFetching/) does what I want it to. It works for a single month. Say I load a month, January, and then change to the day view, the data is cached and does not send an ajax request. But If I change months to Feb and back to Jan, January still reloads.

The author attempted to [accomplish the request back in March of 2011](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=355) but still fell short, I believe. He lets the [browser possibly cache the result of a request](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/#caching), but this is hit or miss and depends on browser settings.

Any ideas? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make my own caching object and use it in the `events` function in the fullcalendar initializer.  This method makes use of the "Events as a function" method of getting your event data: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({

// init options

// go

//here,
    events: function (start, end, callback) {

        //have we already cached this time?
        if (events.eventsCache 
            && events.eventsCache[start.toString + "-" + end.toString]){

                    //if we already have this data, pass it to callback()
            callback(eventsCache[start.toString + "-" + end.toString]);
            return;
        }



        //we haven't gotten this time range (month) yet. get it, and pass it to callback()
        $.get("where_my_events_live.php", function(data){
            if (!events.eventsCache)
                events.eventsCache = {};

            //store your data
            eventsCache[start.toString + "-" + end.toString] = data;
            callback(data);
        });
    },

..r
```

Comment: Hi @Matt H, you are saving the events data directly into javascript array, doing this way increases the used space, you even not compressing the data before adding into local array, please confirm what it is "events.eventsCache", is it is a full calendar pre-defined array or defined by our own, but the idea is good.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplish this by using backbone.js with fullcalendar. http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/ provides code and a tutorial explaining it. It's a bit of an extreme solution for what you're asking to accomplish but the benefits of using backbone.js with fullcalendar may be worth exploring.