# fullcalendar- unable to cache JSON response from AJAX call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, caching, fullcalendar

I'm following thie question [Fullcalendar JSON Feed Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858426/fullcalendar-json-feed-caching)

What I'm trying to do is something similar.
I have a full calendar (only month view enabled so lazy fetching won't work I guess). 
And in the month view, I show user's attendance info. So when user goes to another month (let's say November) an AJAX call is initiated and it returns attendance for that month and if user goes to another month (let's say December) attendance for that month is also fetched.

Problem is, when user returns back to November again, AJAX call is called again. So I have to fetch the data once again. I'm trying to avoid that as it's taking 25 seconds to compute attendance and return the JSON response.
So, I'm trying to cache the response.

Here's a snippet of the JSON.

```
{  
   "attendance":[  
      {  
         "backgroundColor":"#f56954",
         "borderColor":"#f56954",
         "start":"2017-01-01",
         "end":"2017-01-01",
         "title":"Absent",
      },
      {  
         "backgroundColor":"#f56954",
         "borderColor":"#f56954",
         "start":"2017-01-02",
         "end":"2017-01-02",
         "title":"Absent",
      }
   ],
   "leaves":[  

   ]
}
```

I followed the answer provided in that question and made my caching events but it's not working. I don't know why.

Here's my full calendar code.

```
    /* initialize the calendar ----*/
    //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate(),
      m = date.getMonth(),
      y = date.getFullYear();
    var dateofMonth = y + '-' + m + '-' + d;
    var date = dateofMonth;
    var events = [];
    var eventsCache = {}; //for caching

    var today = moment();
    var todayDate = today.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var tomorrow = today.add(1, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month'
      },
      buttonText: {
        today: 'today',
        month: 'month'
      },
      eventMouseover: function(data, event, view) {},
      events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {

        //have we already cached this time?
        if (events.eventsCache && events.eventsCache[start.toString + "-" + end.toString]) {

          //if we already have this data, pass it to callback()
          callback(eventsCache[start.toString + "-" + end.toString]);
          return;
        }

        var date = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
        dateofMonth = date._d;
        var post_url = "path_to_file.php";
        $.ajax({
          url: post_url,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: true,
          data: {
            dateofMonth: dateofMonth,
            csrf_test_name: csrf_token
          },
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {},
          success: function(result) {
            var events = [];
            if (!events.eventsCache)
              events.eventsCache = {};

            //store your data
            eventsCache[start.toString + "-" + end.toString] = result;

            $.each(result.attendance, function(index, res) {
              var date = (res.start).split('-');
              events.push({

                title: res.title,
                allDay: true,

              });
            });

            callback(events);
          }
        });
      },
      editable: false,
      droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caching in the client side is certainly possible as long as you implemented it correctly.
But I see several problems in your code that prevents it from working.

Keep in mind that you are already created `events` and `eventsCache` at the start of your code.

```
var events = [];
var eventsCache = {};
```

These aren't the problems, so keep them.

**Problem #1** is this line:

```
if (events.eventsCache && events.eventsCache[start.toString + "-" + end.toString]) {
```

Here you are checking an object that is always empty, which means the code inside the `if` is never executed.
You need to modify `events.eventsCache` to `eventsCache`, thus the line becomes:

```
if (eventsCache[start.toString + "-" + end.toString]) {
```

There is no need to check the existence of `eventsCache` because you already created it.

**Problem #2** is the first line in `success()` function:

```
var events = [];
```

This line empties the `events` variable everytime `success()` is executed.
In other words, you are emptying the cache, so remove it.

**Problem #3** is the next two lines in the same function:

```
if (!events.eventsCache)
  events.eventsCache = {};
```

This creates an object that is never used, so remove it as well.
Recall that you already created `eventsCache` at the start of your code and you are already using it.
There is no need to create another `eventsCache` object.

That should do it.