# Cache availability for events data on full calendar month view

Tags: http, caching, fullcalendar

Can fullcalendar be able to cache the events data of months view when we navigate from one month to other month view(Prev and Next buttons) as like lazyfetching caches data with in the single month when we navigate to week or day view as it only works for a single month. Say I am on Feb month and then change to the day view, the data is cached and does not send an ajax request. But If I change months to March and back to Feb, Feb still reloads.

Comment: "Say I am on Feb month and then change to the day view, the data is cached and does not send an ajax request"....that's because data has already been loaded for that day, because it was loaded when data for the whole of Feb was loaded. So obviously there is no reason to ask for it again. But if you leave Feb completely, and then come back to it later, it will ask again because there is a chance the events have been updated in the server since then, so a new copy is needed. If you want to do some caching that situation, you'd need to implement it server-side.

Comment: Thank you, server side implementation means should I use browser localstorage or session variables in server side, as per your comments it's not at all possible from full calendar side to keep the previous months search results .

Comment: "server side implementation means should I use browser localstorage or session variables", no you should do some server-side caching. localstorage is client-side, not server-side. And using session variables are not the way you do caching either. I suggest you research this topic a bit more to increase your basic understanding of the concepts.

Comment: _" it's not at all possible from full calendar side to keep the previous months search results"_ ...correct. This is completely intentional. In most usage scenarios users don't actually move from month to month very frequently, and they will generally want to see the latest data from the server if they do - therefore it makes sense to fetch that data on-demand in most situations. The idea also is that it reduces load on your server (and the user's internet connection) by only fetching a small amount of data each time, and only data which is actually going to be seen by the user

Comment: (In contrast, if you just give fullCalendar all your event data whenever it loads the calendar, then this could be a large amount of data (especially if you have an application running for several years with a history of items in it), most of which the user will probably not look at, so that's a waste of resources usually. If your usage scenario is different to this - e.g. your data rarely changes, or you always have data only for a limited time period in your database, or whatever, then you could maybe consider an alternative approach. We would need to know details, to be able to suggest.

Comment: Got it, no.The data size for each month be 8to10 MB, for this case initially I tried WEB localstorage,5MB  available for chrome as it varies based in browsers. I compressed the eventsarray &stored in browser localstorage,through this approach I can  save latest 9 months data, but in IE browser compression logic does not work, and wile compressing the JSON array we have problems if the array contains few special characters, what I am currently trying to do is in server side session scope variables I am saving last 9 searches. Is it be a better approach or can we have any client side approach.

Comment: And by seeing the answer in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858426/fullcalendar-json-feed-caching, I confused whether it's full calendar cache logic and finally understood that they suggested to save events array in javascript array variable, It seems it does not suits the requirement If the date is large in real time applications.

Comment: 10MB of a JSON is really a large amount of event data, I think. How many events are in that size of data, on average? Are you displaying this all on the screen at the same time? if it's 100s of events then I cannot see how the user can find that useful, it's too much information for one person to comprehend all at once. have you considered whether there is a more efficient way to display this information. (Obviously I don't know what the data represents, so I can't give ideas without knowing the whole situation).

Comment: the data consists of 9000 to 10000 records, the user can click on more cells link to go to day view, In day view also he is not able to see the complete details of events by looking on it as glance, and clicking on event a modal popup will be opened with the details, in addition to this there is left side menu contains multiple filters to filter the event records,filter types r like setup status, mailedstatus,mailingstatus,canceled status, If user click on one status the calendar shows only that type of records, and also there are multiple filters like cell name, cell id, mailingid & category.

Comment: Even the month view of calendar has 10000 cells, all the event records gets populated with out any issues, and the left side filters seems to working as expected .based on our selection .

Comment: Ok fair enough. I think in the circumstances, from what you have mentioned now, your approach is quite reasonable.

Comment: So it sounds like really your problem is actually related to a) issues with compressing JSON data, and b) problems with legacy support for IE. Maybe it would be better to ask separate, specific questions about these topics, which are not really related to fullCalendar directly.

Comment: wow, this is the first time you completely agree with my situation, even my problem does not resolve I am happy with your suggestion. Can you please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858426/fullcalendar-json-feed-caching, as the suggestion in this link, can I compress the events array and saved in local JS variables to keep the last 6 searches. As of now I am saving the last 9 event arrays in session variable, but the problem is to get the server side session array variable to JS code I need to use an ajax call, so ajax call still takes more time to get 10MB array to jscode.

Comment: I don't think there is any way around that really, unless you load 100s of MB of data up-front when the user first loads that page, and then keep it there in localstorage, and load it statically into fullCalendar without ever talking to the server. That would result in a terrible first-time experience of the page though. And ultimately, if you need the data in the calendar then you have to download it at some point. Your only decision is about when to download it, and how often, and how big each download is. You definitely need to get compression working to make it faster.

Comment: Most HTTP servers offer built-in compression which you can set up, you likely don't need to code it yourself.